# Facing problem in Multiprocessing iteration

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Hello I am  new in Multiprocessing

I have large list =['01037695536','01037695936','01087695536'.....] and so on
I am doing Multiprocessing using Pool for parallel processing

without parallel processing my function call was

```
datalist=value_pass(mylist)
```

it returns a list after calculation and I can iterate over my parameter list in my value_pass function.The value_pass function contains nested loops

```
import multiprocessing
p=multiprocessing.Pool()
datalist=p.map(value_pass,mylist)
```

what I have figured out that after a parallel processing pool. my list value is not properly iterated over in function value_pass. It is split as an example '01037695536' turns into 0

01037695936 turns into 0 and so on. I have checked that my cpu resource use all its core. but my result shows this odd thing.

my output:

```
my list 01037695536
my list 01023618180
my list 01066680824
my element in first forloop 0
my list 01043941378
my list 01016322002
my element first forloop 0
my element first forloop 0
```

so this is the split value I suppose.  how could I iterate over whole value  using multiprocessing. I want to see  My element in the first loop  01043941378 instead of 0.

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
#import itertools
#import os
def value_pass(text):
    mylist=text
    print("id list",mylist)
    begin=timer()
    sum_val=0
    list_avg_score=[]
    list_category_val=[]
    dict_list=[]
    #Avg_score=0
    #print("Worker process id for {0}: {1}".format(minicustomer, os.getpid()))
    #print("------------------------------------------------------------------")
    with graphdriver.session()as session:
        for i in mylist:


            print("element in first forloop", i)
            for key in list_of_unique_merchants:
                print("Here at list_of_unique_merchants customer value is ",i)
                print("BMCC_Code",key)
                valuelist=list_of_unique_merchants[key]
                #print("Uniquelistfor:",key,valuelist)
                for j in  valuelist:

                    #print("list len",len(valuelist))
                    #print("Here the iner of value list ",i)
                          #print("--------------------------------")
                    #print([i,j])
                    pref_attach_score=Prefer_Attachment_query2([i,j])
                    #print(pref_attach_score)

                    result=session.run(pref_attach_score)
                    for line in result:
                        #print(line["score"])
                        sum_val=sum_val+line["score"]
                    #Avg_score=sum_val/len(valuelist) 


                Totalsumval=sum_val
                print("Totalsum",Totalsumval)
                Avg_score=sum_val/len(valuelist)
                print("Avg_score",Avg_score)
                sum_val=0
                list_avg_score.append(Avg_score)
                list_category_val.append(key)
                avg_score_list=list_avg_score
                category_list=list_category_val


                #print("sumval is now",sum_val)



                #print(result)
            max_dictionary  =MaxValue_calc(i,category_list,avg_score_list) 
            #MaxValue_calc(i,category_list,avg_score_list) 

            print("max_dicitionary",max_dictionary)
            dict_list.append(max_dictionary)
            rowlist=dict_list
            print('appended list',rowlist)
            print('process',len(rowlist))

            #dict_list=[]
            list_avg_score=[] 
            list_category_val=[]

            #print("rowlist", rowlist)
            #print("list_category_val is now",list_category_val)

            #print("for",i," category AVG scores is now ",category_list)


            #print("list_avg_score is now",list_avg_score)
            #print("for",i," category AVG scores is now ",avg_score_list)



    session.close()
    end=timer()
    print("Total time   :",(end-begin))
    return rowlist
```

Comment: Could you share your function `value_pass`? Basically it has to be modified. You have to take out the loop over the values of `mylist` and only define the elementary operation done on each element of `mylist`. The multiprocessing worker will each take one value from `mylist` and apply the function to this element.

Comment: sure i am adding it

Comment: a [mre] will be really helpful. As it stands it seems like you are passing each data(`01037695536`) to the pool, so the workers iterate on that. You might want to eliminate one loop level (remeber that `pool.map` itself is like a loop level)